# Titanium - Get image file from filesystem on Android

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy, titanium-android

I have a problem getting an image from filesystem. On iOS works fine.

First of all, I save a remote image in the filesystem with this function:

img.imagen = url from the remote image (e.g. http://onesite.es/img2.jpeg)

```
function descargarImagen(img, callback){

    var path = img.imagen;
    var filename = path.split("/").pop();

    var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient({
        onload: function() {
            // first, grab a "handle" to the file where you'll store the downloaded data
            var f = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, filename);
            f.write(this.responseData); // write to the file
            Ti.API.debug("-- Imagen guardada: " + f.nativePath);
            callback({path: f.nativePath});
        },
        timeout: 10000
    });
    xhr.open('GET', path);
    xhr.send();
}
```

Now, I want to share this image creating an Android Intent:

args.image = f.nativePath(in the previous function)

```
var intent      = null;
var intentType  = null;

intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
    action: Ti.Android.ACTION_SEND
});

// add text status
if (args.status){
    intent.putExtra(Ti.Android.EXTRA_TEXT, args.status);
}

// change type according to the content
if (args.image){
    intent.type = "image/*";
    intent.putExtraUri(Ti.Android.EXTRA_STREAM, args.image);
}else{
    intent.type = "text/plain";
    intent.addCategory(Ti.Android.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
}

// launch intent
Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(Ti.Android.createIntentChooser(intent, args.androidDialogTitle));
```

What I'm doing wrong?